# Wallet that can only hold 2 cards

Tags: cash

Most slim wallets are designed to hold cash and 6-7 cards. I need one that only holds 2 cards max, and has no space for cash. Preferably a vertically loading one, so I can insert the card into the wallet straight out of a chip card reader, before it's even done reading.

Kinda like this, but this one has a backside with 2 additional layers of material:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GNX42Q2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GNX42Q2)
[image]

This one is cool too, but has 2 layers of fabric and holds up to 8 cards, which means it will be loose with 2 [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FK7DFH4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FK7DFH4)

Comment: This one is damn close, https://www.ebay.com/itm/Mens-Wallet-Minimalist-Slim-ID-Credit-Card-Holder-Beige-Waxed-Leather/273666410001 but it holds 3 cards+cash. It does it without extra material for the extra cards. Looks like it has great build quality. Closest one yet.

Comment: This one snugly holds 2 cards, and a third less snugly https://www.ebay.com/itm/Minimalist-Genuine-Leather-Credit-Card-Case-Holder-Slim-Wallet-Mens-Women-5-slot/254030272938

Answer (score 1):

You can have a wallet custom fit on eBay or etsy, just message the seller, such as this one:

I had him make it so that 3 cards would be too tight to use comfortably. Another thing to keep in mind is the indentations on some cards make them tighter than others. Without squeezing it takes about 25 pounds of force to pull a non indented card out of my wallet, squeezing takes that down to around 10lb. Wear and tear should lower the force over time.

[image]
https://www.ebay.com/itm/273675517893?ViewItem=&item=273675517893

Answer (score 0):

Credit cards are about the size of business cards, so anything that accommodates a business card has a fighting chance.

Some physical diaries have plastic or leather slots or ‘pouches’ that take a business card. Each slot holds 1 card comfortably and probably two snugly. Cut one of these out and put your pair of cards in it. When it wears out, cut another one out to replace it.